# EF Core CSV Upload Check if data exists takes a lot of time

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am currently parsing a CSV file with 15.000+ lines. I need to insert all of them in my database, but every line contains data that need to be inserted to multiple entites.

The problem that I have is that I need to check for each line if the data exists already in my database, if not I insert it with BulkInsert at the end.

But it takes a lot of time to check for each line if the data exists already (entites.FirstOrDefault(...))... I mean it "only" takes 30-50ms to check if it exists, but to do this 15.000+ times, ends up taking several minutes for the whole operation.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: EF isn't suited for batch or bulk data operations - what I'd do is perform as much ETL (Extract/Transform/Load) as possible within the database, perhaps using a stored-procedure with a Table-valued parameter and a `MERGE` statement (with table-locking, if that suits your application).

Comment: Some EF scaffolding tools (like https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) will generate `DbContext` methods for table-valued stored-procedures.

Comment: Depending on how much data is in the database and what properties you need to compare against, it is also possible to load (part of) the data into memory (with `AsNoTracking()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can bulk insert and check for constraints (e.g. unique key constraints):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=netframework-4.8

So if some id in the .csv is unique as well in the db you can use that to do a bulk insert which checks for duplicate key. Know i think that when when using this the operation would fail completely if duplicates are found in the source and sink, but it could also be that the bulkinsert only inserts the unqiue values and the check is done on a row basis. Should be worth to investigate if this is applicable to your use-case.

Now when dealing with large numbers, its always better to use the most native version of a system, and sql servers are no different. So try to directly deal with the database engine instead of EF.

That being said something you could try:

1. Create a table called `CsvImportStaging` which would be a copy of your target table
2. Bulkinsert the .csv file data into `CsvImportStaging`
3. Now copy all unique values from `CsvImportStaging` to your source values*
4. `TRUNCATE` the `CsvImportStaging` table

Be sure to apply appropriate locking to the staging and target table to make this whole ordeal atomic if you're dealing with multiple producers/consumers.

* Once again use a direct query and not ef
e.g. something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Id) SELECT WHERE Id NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM Table1);
```

It will take some experimenting as to what query would be the most performant.
I think you could also do something with a (`OUTER`)`JOIN` instead of `WHERE .. IN` since joins can be quite fast.
I've also seen the `MERGE` statement in transact-sql but i haven't used it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15